# Fully transparent mask -> fully opaque widget

Tags: python, qt, qt4, pyside

I ran into a strange corner case when attempting to render a fully transparent widget in `PySide`.

If I call `setMask` with a `QBitmap` that is filled with `Qt.color0`, it makes the widget completely opaque (rather than completely transparent, as I would expect).

Putting in a single pixel of `Qt.color` leads to the expected behavior: the widget becomes completely transparent other than that single pixel.

Below is a minimal example.  Changing the variable `single_pixel` to `True` fills in the top left pixel, which causes the mask to start working as expected.

Any ideas what's going on here?

```
import sys
from PySide import QtCore, QtGui

app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)

widget = QtGui.QWidget()
widget.resize(200, 200)
widget.show()

bitmap = QtGui.QBitmap(widget.size())
bitmap.clear()

single_pixel = False
if single_pixel:
    painter = QtGui.QPainter()
    painter.begin(bitmap)
    painter.setPen(QtCore.Qt.color1)
    painter.drawPoint(0,0)
    painter.end()

widget.setMask(bitmap)

sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`QWidget::setMask(QBitmap)` converts `QBitmap` to `QRegion` and calls `QWidget::setMask(QRegion)`. `QRegion` produced by empty bitmap is empty. So using empty bitmap in `setMask` is equal to `widget.setMask(QRegion())`. Qt assumes that providing empty region means unsetting mask. This is reasonable because there is no other validity flag in `QRegion` besides `isEmpty`. `QWidget::mask` returns empty region when no mask is set according to documentation, so empty QRegion is apparently treated as a special value meaning that no mask is set.

In `QWidget::setMask(QRegion)`:

```
d->extra->mask = newMask;
d->extra->hasMask = !newMask.isEmpty();
```

This is probably a bug in Qt documentation. `QWidget::setMask` docs should contain a note about this.